# Django drag-n-drop form validation

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

DJANGO 2.0

So basically I was tasked to make a drag and drop form, in which I would have a table of available users, and create a team from that table, by dragging and dropping the users.

My problem is, that I have no idea where to start tackling this problem, mostly because I'm not sure how to validate the data that is dropped after I hit submit.

So my goals are:

> Validate drag-n-drop data
>
> Add a user status so it won't be reassigned to another team.
>
> Assign credits to users upon competition of the given task (this is used for making reports and to add an "achievements" functionalities)

Anything leading to drag-n-drop validation in django will be helpful too

My models.py for users

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    department = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        default=''
    )
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=60,
        default=''
    )
    date_joined = models.DateField(
         default=datetime.date.today
    )
    avatar = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="avatars"
    )
```

My models.py for creating the teams, (I still need to write a Foreign Key or something to store the users that will be on the team):

```
class Task(models.Model):

    Task_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=15,
        default=""
    )

    Task_date = models.DateField()
    Task_deadline = models.DateField()

    Task_credits = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=2,
        decimal_places=0
    )
    Task_reference = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        default=''
    )
    Task_description = models.TextField(
        max_length=3000
    )
    Task_notes = models.TextField(
        max_length=500
    )

    Task_completition = models.CharField(
        max_length=15,
        default=_lazy('Assigned')
        choices=
    )
    Task_tags = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        default='',
    )
```